# What component is angular-route

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I installed the generator-angular with yeoman:

Inside the `bower.json` I see this dependency which I also agreed to install.

but now I see I do need the angular ui router not the default angular-route.

Is this the angular core routing?

If yes why can it be installed extra?

If no what is this angular-route then? Googling it gives nothing unique...

`"angular-route": "1.2.6",`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be the bower package to install the `ngRoute` module. The source is found at:

https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route

Comment: Ok then its just what I thought angular-route is the default routing mechanism that I do not need. I just installed angular-ui-router :)

Answer (score 2):

with bower:

bower install --save angular-route

in the main page :

```
<script src="/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
```

in your app:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

its all!

if you want more automatic import, you can install [wiredep](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep), wiredep injects yours dependencies into your source code, reading the bower.json file in this case.

Answer (score 0):

At a Windows cmd prompt:

```
> cd <path to your project>
> bower install angular-route
```

Bower will download to:

```
<path to your project>\bower_components\angular-route
```

And you can reference in your .html file via relative path:

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
```